# Why are airline passengers asked to lift up window shades during takeoff and landing?

Tags: air-travel, regulations, aircraft

I have always wondered why the windows shades have to be raised during take off and landing. I can't think of any safety issues by having a closed window.

Comment: I suspect that it's highly airline and region specific. I don't recall having been asked to open the window shades in any of my (many) flights in the past few years.

Comment: I thought I noticed this on all flights involving night time (or simulated night time), but maybe it's just confirmation bias?

Comment: I have told people it's so the passengers can see the flames on the engines. When they scream, it alerts the captain.

Comment: This was asked a while back on Skeptics: [Why do we open the window shades during landing and take-off?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8849/5933) and it's worth having a look, as their top answer looks into what legal rules do or don't exist around this matter.

Comment: FWIW, I was on a charter flight about ten years ago that was the exact opposite -- the crew insisted on the shades being closed for takeoff and landing.... O_o

Comment: Apart from the highly improbable events mentioned by others, I can think of a day to day use for this. Most aircrafts usually bump a few times while landing. Depending on the pilot and other conditions, these can be very bad thuds. Knowing exactly when this occurs can help in preparing your body for it.

Comment: Here's a post from 20 years ago, close to when the rules started. You can see from this the reasons that existed when the practice started: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.travel.air/5Cq-UpY0yv4

Answer (score 364, accepted):

I will answer this with a very long answer since aviation safety is my day to day job.

The window shade opening is a part of a long process to prepare the cabin for sudden (unexpected) emergencies. Why is that? Well, cabin crew have only **90 seconds** to evacuate all passengers in case of emergencies. The process of evacuation itself should not take more than 90 seconds regardless of the size of the aircraft or the number of passengers. So to make the evacuation possible in 90 seconds cabin crew and other airline staff will prepare every flight in advance to make this possible. One example is the emergency exits, only healthy adults are allowed to occupy these seats, they are also required to read the safety card for emergency exits to make them prepared in case of emergencies to help the cabin crew. They are called ABPs (Able-Bodied-Persons). This is just one example.

Anyway, window shades opening is a small part of a long preparation process. Passengers are asked to open window shades before take offs and landings because these are considered to be **critical times** in aviation. Many things can go wrong during these times (most accidents do happen during take offs or landings), so people are asked to open window shades along with other things (seats in an upright position, people seated and buckled etc.) to make everything prepared as if the plane were in an emergency. In case something goes wrong (God forbid) things will be ready in advance so cabin crew can easily evacuate people in the short period of 90 seconds.

Specific reasons behind the window shade opening include:

- Passengers are curious, hence they are perfect *extra eyes* to see if something goes wrong out there. Usually, passengers report stuff right away.
- In case of sudden emergencies, every second counts. Therefore if shades are open crew can easily see outside conditions to help them in planning the evacuation (which doors to use for evacuation etc.).
- In case of emergency (which is more likely during take offs and landings) people should be prepared just in case. So during the daytime, opening window shades and putting cabin lights to full makes the eyes used to sunlight so if something goes wrong and passengers need to be evacuated there will not be a sudden change in light contrast which might lead to temporary blurred vision. The same thing at night flights, window shades are open and cabin lights are dimmed.
- It helps ground emergency personnel outside to see the inside of the cabin.

These rules might be different from one airline to another, but in general, almost all airlines require their crews to make sure of the window shades during take offs and landings. They also add it in the preparation announcements prior to take offs and landings.

Comment: As a friend of a cabin crew, I can back up this 90 seconds requirement for evacuation and seats occupied by ABPs. It's part of their initial training and they've a final test where they MUST evacuate a plane full of smoke in less than 90 seconds or FAIL their qualification. No need to hurry but everything must be executed smoothly. ABPs will help by not blocking, showing others what to do and after they're out of plane will help for "reception" of elder or disabled passengers, children and (the worst) scaried adults. **Window shades**: yes you must see engines, wings, tarmac or sea outside

Comment: Example of what is a [90 second evacuation test, part of qualification of the Airbus A380](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1uzne_a380-emergency-evacuation-test_tech). That was part of the initial problem conceiving a 858 passengers plane. As any other plane, it *must* be able to evacuate its passengers in less than 90 seconds or else Airbus just lost billions of Euro! Watch the video and think about all the things you won't have the time to do if it happens...

Comment: @FelipeAls the number of doors, emergency doors, escape slides, slide rafts, equipment and crew are all calculated carefully to match the number of passengers to achieve the maximum safety possible including the 90 second evacuation rule.

Comment: IIRC, one of the things is that you must be able to evacuate to one side if the other is on fire. Having the windows open helps in figuring out which side is on fire.

Comment: I always thought it was to reduce air-sickness.

Comment: Those reasons must be really bad,I have flown 1000 times in Europe, not once have I heard someone say one should open the shades.

Comment: @Fuqtard I said it in my answer, things can be different from one airlines to another. Plus, there could be this rules but cabin crews are not applying it...

Comment: You forgot one more reason. Assuming it's daylight, if the cabin were to lose power having the shades up will help light up the cabin

Comment: From http://pogue.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/09/12/the-many-mysteries-of-air-travel/?src=recg&_r=0,   "Makes it easier for the flight attendants to assess any exterior hazards— fire, debris — that might interfere with an emergency evacuation"

Comment: While this is an excellent answer, the bullet points are the most important part of the answer, as they actually answer the question. They should be much closer to the top of the article. The remainder of the article is good, but not *as* important as the bullet points.

Comment: @corsiKa You are right, the bullet points are the answer, but the rest is an explanation of idea behind the idea of why passengers got to do some stuff in advance. Some people might think this is silly so I tried to explain the window shades issue and the story behind it..

Comment: You could just say **Passengers are curious, hence they are perfect extra eyes to see if something goes wrong out there** and **putting cabin lights to full makes the eyes used to sunlight**

Comment: Isn't it better to tell passengers why rather than keeping this a mystery?

Comment: So is it better (in the event of an emergency) to not use the reading light above your head when they dim the cabin lights for takeoff and landing?

Comment: @FelipeAls I didn't expect this link to a french video in which the crew speaks german, on an english site.

Comment: why only 90 sec? neither less nor more??

Answer (score 37):

The majority of airline evacuations happen as a result of events during takeoff and landing.  The reason to open the windows is to see outside.  For example, you do not want to open the emergency exit door over the wing if the wing is on fire.  Combine the two and one concludes that it is a good idea to open the windows during takeoff and landing.

My source is a flight attendant that I asked this question of a while back.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different (and more cynical) view: Air Canada wants them open, United doesn't care. Lufthansa wants you to take the headsets off during take off and landing, Delta doesn't care. If there was a really good reason for these types of measure, the airlines would use them consistently. No airline is interested in a spotty safety record, so they probably take a good look at these procedures before the decide to adopt them or not. This would indicate that most of these are feel-good measures with no real scientific support.

The only notable exception would be extra revenue for the airlines: until recently it was absolutely forbidden to use any wireless device in transmitting mode during a flight since it clearly wasn't safe. But then the airlines figured they can charge for WIFI during a flight and all of a sudden it's perfectly fine to have dozens of WIFI nodes on the plane blasting at full throttle.

Comment: On-board WiFi is switched off by cabin personnel during take off and landing. It's true that different airlines have different rules. That's because there's constant progress and research and not all airlines or countries follow suit at once.